# pbsdsh: What happened to PBS_VNODE (and other mysteries)

Tags: bash, pbs

I am trying to figure out how to use `pbsdsh`.  I have a PBS script and a bash script.  The PBS script looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash

## Required PBS Directives --------------------------------------
#PBS -A blahblahblah
#PBS -q debug
#PBS -l select=1:ncpus=32:mpiprocs=2
#PBS -l walltime=00:00:30
#PBS -j oe
#

## Execution Block
# Environment Setup ----------------------------------------------
cd $PBS_O_WORKDIR

pbsdsh -v $PBS_O_WORKDIR/greetings.bash

exit $?
```

The bash script `greetings.bash` will hopefully be much more involved very soon, but for now all it has is:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
#echo ::: $PBS_NODENUM :::  $PBS_VNODENUM :::

exit 0
```

I submit to PBS and get the output:

```
::: 0 ::: :::
::: 0 ::: :::
pbsdsh: spawned task 0x00000000 on logical node 0 event 2
pbsdsh: spawned task 0x00000001 on
```

So, first question: Why does the script find a value for `$PBS_NODENUM` but `$PBS_VNODENUM` is undefined?

Here's another question:

In the PBS script, I am `cd`'ing to `$PBS_O_WORKDIR`, and then running `$PBS_O_WORKDIR/greetings.bash`.  But then I think, well, I'm already in `$PBS_O_WORKDIR`, so surely I don't have to specify it again in the `pbsdsh` command.  "`./greetings.bash`" should be sufficient.  Right?  So I make that change to the script, and I get no results at all.  I get the error messages:

```
: No such file or directory
: No such file or directory
```

Why should that happen?  BTW, I saw an example with a script with the line `PATH=$PBS_O_PATH` and I tried inserting that into `greetings.bash`.  No change.